# I want to use Repl.it in Ruby programming and read an UNICODE text file but it does not work. It makes ERROR message

Tags: ruby, unicode, ascii, replit

So,

There is a text file with hungarian letters, but the compiler does not want to execute my code. How can I solve it. I uploaded a text file and want to modify it, but it does not read in because it is not US-ASCII.

Does anybody else met with this probleme?

The error message:

"\xC3" on US-ASCII
(repl):4:in `puts'
(repl):4:in`puts'
(repl):4:in `block in <main>'
(repl):2:in`each'
(repl):2:in `'

MY CODE IS:

```
file="2014.txt"
```

File.readlines(file).each do |line|
a= "2014.evi.nyomtatvanyok/" + line
puts a
end

the text file contais that:

Bevallás iparûzési adófeltöltési kötelezettségrõl 2013
Gépjármûadó-kedvezmény mentesség bevallás 2013
Helyi iparûzési adóbevallás 2013
Idegenforgalmi adóbevallás 2013 
Kommunális adóbevallás 2013 
Talajterhelési díj bevallás 2013

Comment: Please show error message.

Comment: Here comes the error message:"\xC3" on US-ASCII
(repl):4:in `puts'
(repl):4:in `puts'
(repl):4:in `block in <main>'
(repl):2:in `each'
(repl):2:in `<main>'

Comment: As a rough guess I'd say your file is utf8 encoded. Is there some way of telling your code this.

Comment: I tried to change the encoding with Komodo Edit but there is no change. How could you solve it?

Comment: That does not look like a Ruby error message. It is either truncated, in which case you need to post the *full* error message, not just a part of it, or it is coming from something other than Ruby, in which case you need to tell us where it is coming from.

Comment: I have tried that with built in Ruby in Lubuntu without error message instead the special characters turned to "?" character. As I said I have tried to change the character coding but there is no effect. And I thought there is an other solution I installed an Hungarian language Lubuntu with Ruby but that was not solution too and I have searched for hungarian pack to Ruby but there is not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines:

```
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
```

to the top of your code file.